# PHP Cron - Max Allocation?

Tags: ubuntu, php, cron, memory-usage

I'm getting email errors from a cron, on Ubuntu, that lives at:

```
/etc/cron.d/php5
```

I didn't install that cron, so I'm guessing it is installed with PHP. Its contents are as follows:

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +\
$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```

It seems to be the cron that kills old sessions.

It is however, sending me this email error:

```
To: root

Subject: Cron <root@mailserver> [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete (failed)

Message:
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
find: invalid argument `-delete' to `-cmin'
```

Does anyone know how to go about remedying this?

**EDIT:** I know that 262144 bytes is not very much, so perhaps I should just bump up the memory limit? I figure that is a workaround, but I was just curious as to why these errors suddenly started popping up. There are never actually any `$_SESSION`s created on this server, it's only used to send email.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly related to the `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` script being called.  What happens when you run that manually?  How are you running PHP on your system?  Are you using mod_php, cgi, fcgi, or something else?  Anyway, look at that script, and figure out where it is breaking.

Comment: @Zoredache: I'm running it through cron triggered PHP scripts, so cli. And that file is a shell script, with this line causing an immediate error: `php5 -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -r 'print ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");'`

Comment: @Zoredache: Weird. -c specifies the .ini file. In that file, I have `memory_limit = 1024MB`, and running just: `php5 -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -r 'echo "here";'` causes the same error, `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
Could not startup.`

Comment: @Zoredache: And that's the error. It was set to `1024MB`, instead of `1024M`. The value was illegal. Since I don't run it as an Apache module, I never knew. I'll just update maxlifetime.sh to use the cli config. Thanks!

Comment: Since you solved your problem, you should add an answer, and accept it.

Comment: @Zoredache: I know, I've been on SO for some time :)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was in the way the Apache2 version of my .ini file was configured. It was set to allow for 1024MB of memory, rather than the correct 1024M. Someone else must have been messing around in it, since I'm only using PHP on this server via CLI.